# Render partial template base on condition in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partial-views

I have 2-column layout. Some controller has left column, some not. What is the best way to render it depend on controller? Now, it look likes that:

```
<% if params[:controller] != 'page' %>
        <div id="navigation" class="l"><%= render "layouts/left-menu" %></div>
    <% end  %>
```

It's bad, bad monkey code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Changed my solution, OP wanted condition to depend on action **and** controller.

In your base helper, define a method like this:

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def has_left_menu?
    @has_left_menu.nil? ? 
      true : # <= default, change to preference
      @has_left_menu
  end
end
```

In your application controller:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController
  def enable_left_menu!
    @has_left_menu = true
  end
  def disable_left_menu!
    @has_left_menu = false
  end
end
```

In your view or layout, change your check to this:

```
<% if has_left_menu? %>
    <div id="navigation" class="l"><%= render "layouts/left-menu" %></div>
<% end  %>
```

Now you can disable/enable the left menu in `before_filters` or anywhere else in your action:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # enable left menu for "index" action in this controller
  before_filter :enable_left_menu!, :only => [:index]

  # disable left menu for all actions in this controller
  before_filter :disable_left_menu!

  def index
    # dynamic left menu status based on some logic
    disable_left_menu! if params[:left_menu] == 'false'
  end
end
```

Comment: But if I need divide by action?

Comment: Why is this better than using the layout method in the controller? This is less DRY, more code and less understandable for other developers that might see this code.

Comment: Your solution is the best for choosing which layout file to use from a controller. All the author is trying to do is have conditions in their views. I think `layouts/_left-menu.html.erb` is in fact a partial not a layout as you think. At least that is how it is being used.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you use layout like this

```
#PublicController is just an example
class PublicController < ApplicationController
  layout "left-menu"
end
```

And in the views/layouts folder you put the left-menu.html.erb

with a stylesheet_link_tag to your spesific css file

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'left-menu' %>
```

You can learn more at [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Comment: But I have a lot of controllers, that must render left-menu. I must add layout to each controller?

Comment: the file application.html.erb in views/layouts is the default. If you want your controller to use this layout you don't need this line. If you need another layout for a controller this is the rails way to do it. All other solutions are monkey patching and breaks the rails role of convention over configuration. :)